# Dynamic values passing in Prepared Statement

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I am using Clojure.java.jdbc for database access in clojure.
I wanted to use prepared statements with select.

From my previous question I got the answer like this,

```lisp
(jdbc/query (:conn dbinfo) 
            ["select * from users where username = ? and password = ?" 
             "harikk09" 
             "amma123"])
```

It is working also.

Now,

this parameter list I want to make dynamic. so I write a function like,

```lisp
(defn values-builder (fn[param] (:value @(:value (param 1)))))
```

which actually works correctly and return a collection of values using a println.

```lisp
(println (map values-builder params))
```

gives

```lisp
(harikk09 amma123)
```

But when I tried to execute it like this, where sql-query is the previously mentioned query

```lisp
(jdbc/query (:conn dbinfo) sql-query (map values-builder params))
```

, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: 
Clojure.lang.LazySeq@ab5111fa
```

Can anyone help me to rectify this error?

I think clojure expects a list of parameters without () or [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC query and prepared values together need to be a collection. So you need to make a collection out of a string and a collection of parametrized values. To prepend a single item onto the front of a collection, use `cons`

```
(jdbc/query (:conn dbinfo) (cons sql-query (map values-builder params)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use apply to splice in the arguments

```
(apply jdbc/query (:conn dbinfo) sql-query (map values-builder params))
```

Update: as noted below apply won't work since sql needs to be in a vector with the params
in that case you need to cons the sql query onto the generated params list

```
(jdbc/query (:conn dbinfo) (cons sql-query (map values-builder params)))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it and got an Exception:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: apply is used if you want to apply a collection of all parameters as separate parameters to a function. Here he needs the items of a collection to be added to the second parameter, which is supposed to be a collection of string and prepared values. So no combination of partial and apply is going to make that work.